# Remove special characters in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a code which looks up a string in database and returns result that partially matches the given string -

Ex If "Pet" is my string to be searched on database, the results would be

1. Pete
2. Petere
3. Pett
4. P.Petere (my code doesnt return value with dot / space (4))

"P.Peter" is my string to be searched, it should give me the result

1. Pete
2. Petere
3. P.Petere

However as of now my code doesn't return values without dot / space (3).

Below is my code - `VlookUp` is my worksheet with string, `data` is my worksheet containing database.. In `VlookUp`, A2 contains my string to be matched and results are in row 8,

```
Sub MyVlookUp()
    Dim Str As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng As Range

    Sheets("VlookUp").Select
    Range("B8:C300").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Str = Worksheets("VlookUp").Range("A8").Value
    Worksheets("data").Activate
    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B1", ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp))
    Set c = SrchRng.Find(Str, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            Range(Cells(c.Row, 2), Cells(c.Row, 3)).Copy
            With Worksheets("VlookUp")
            .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
            End With

            Set c = SrchRng.FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
     Worksheets("VlookUp").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure, that query `P.Peter` should result with record `Pete`?

Comment: Trying to get search results that are subsets of the string (so the more exhaustive the return values are the better for me). However my code doesnt recognize space, special characters while giving results.

Comment: One way I could think of is, that I make my code remove space, dot etc from the string to be searched as well as the database values before starting the search. That condition when appended to my current code can give results, however it would screw up the return values. I was looking for return values to be the same as in database.

Comment: Does it behave the same when you also specify LookAt:=xlPart?

Comment: @Limak Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: @BerndStoeckel No it doesnt change anything :(

Comment: Perhaps like you said, you could perform the search multiple times, once with the original string then again removing the special characters and using `Left()` `Right()` `Mid()` to remove one or two characters from the start / end to pick up more similiar results?